# Azure WebJobs that combine queue triggered functions and Scheduled triggered functions

Tags: c#, azure-functions

I don't know if I can combine two queue triggered functions with a third schedule triggered functions.  Here is the code followed by the console output from webjob.exe. The output from webjob.exe does not show that webjob is finding the third function.

```
[13:36:49 INF] Starting JobHost
[13:36:49 INF] Found the following functions:
WebJob.Functions.ProcessMonitorMessage
WebJob.Functions.ProcessControllerLogMessage
```

```
public class Functions
    {
        readonly ILogger _logger;
        public Functions(ILogger logger) => _logger = logger.ForContext<Functions>();
        public void ProcessMonitorMessage([QueueTrigger("monitors1")] string message)
            {
                Helper.ControllerMonitor monitor = new Helper.ControllerMonitor();
                try 
                {
                    monitor = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Helper.ControllerMonitor>(message);
                }
                catch 
                {
                    Helper.WriteError("we had an error deserializing:" + message);
                    return;
                }

                Task<bool> isSuccess = Helper.SaveMonitor(monitor);
                if (!isSuccess.Result)
                    Helper.WriteError("we had an error updating:" + message);
            }
            public void ProcessControllerLogMessage([QueueTrigger("controllerlogs1")] string message)
            {
                Helper.LogRecord log = new Helper.LogRecord();
                try
                {
                    log = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Helper.LogRecord>(message);
                }
                catch
                {
                    Helper.WriteError("we had an error deserializing:" + message);
                    return;
                }

                Task<bool> isSuccess = Helper.SaveLog(log);
                if (!isSuccess.Result)
                    Helper.WriteError("we had an error saving:" + message);
            }
        //Run([TimerTrigger("%TimerSchedule%")]  example using embeded variable
        
        [FunctionName("TimerTriggerCSharp")]
        public static void Run([TimerTrigger("0 */5 * * * *")] TimerInfo myTimer, ILogger _logger)
        {
            Helper.WriteInformation("Delete web jobs started");
            Helper.DeleteOldEventLogs();
        }

    }
```

```
{
  "BatchSize": 1000,
  "FlushTimeout": "00:00:30",
  "IsEnabled": true
}
[13:36:49 INF] QueuesOptions
{
  "BatchSize": 16,
  "NewBatchThreshold": 32,
  "MaxPollingInterval": "00:00:02",
  "MaxDequeueCount": 5,
  "VisibilityTimeout": "00:00:00"
}
[13:36:49 INF] SingletonOptions
{
  "LockPeriod": "00:00:15",
  "ListenerLockPeriod": "00:00:15",
  "LockAcquisitionTimeout": "10675199.02:48:05.4775807",
  "LockAcquisitionPollingInterval": "00:00:05",
  "ListenerLockRecoveryPollingInterval": "00:01:00"
}
[13:36:49 INF] BlobsOptions
{
  "CentralizedPoisonQueue": false
}
[13:36:49 INF] Starting JobHost
[13:36:49 INF] Found the following functions:
WebJob.Functions.ProcessMonitorMessage
WebJob.Functions.ProcessControllerLogMessage

[13:36:49 INF] Job host started
[13:36:49 INF] Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
[13:36:49 INF] Hosting environment: Development
[13:36:49 INF] Content root path: D:\Users\jrhol\Source\Repos\limited-mobility-solutions-development\LimitedMobilitySolutionsAzure\WebJob\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1
```

Answer (score 0):

I found an old reference from 2017 that would have been an old version of .net core that referenced a function AddTimers(). On a guess I looked for a current function sound-a-like. And there is an AddTimers(). Just need to use injection to get there.

```
IHostBuilder builder = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder()
 
                .UseSerilog(Log.Logger)

                .ConfigureServices(s => {
                    s.AddSingleton(Log.Logger);
                    s.AddHostedService<LifetimeEventsHostedService>();
                })
        
                .ConfigureWebJobs(b =>
                {
                    b.AddAzureStorageCoreServices();
                    b.AddAzureStorage();
                    b.AddTimers();
                });
```

I also needed to make a change in how I invoked the function.

```
 public static void DeleteLogs([TimerTrigger("0 0 22 * * *")] TimerInfo myTimer)
{
}
```

And changed the CRON to run at 10PM.

Apparently, Visual Studio sets this up for you either storage queue triggered or a schedule but not both. Now ready for integration testing.